# Infimum of the Upper Sums

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, riemann-sum, stieltjes-integral

Let $P$ be the partition of the interval $[a,b]$. If $P$ is divided into two partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that $P_1$ covers the interval $[a,c]$ and $P_2$ covers the interval $[c,b]$, then $U(P, f, α) = U(P_1, f, α) + U(P_2, f, α)$.
But if we take infimum of all such upper sums over different partitions on both sides there comes an inequality $$\inf\{U(P, f, α) : P\text{ is a partition of }[a,b]\} \ge \\\inf\{U(P_1, f, α) : P_1 \text{ is a partition of }[a,c]\} + \inf\{U(P_2, f, α) : P_2 \text{ is a partition of }[c,b]\}$$ Why?

Here α is a monotonic increasing function.

Comment: The infimum with respect to what? What is the $\alpha$ here? Please add detail to your question so that it is self-contained.

Comment: @TheoBendit Actually there will be a set of different uppers sums formed due to various possible partitions and then taking the infimum of that set. I am sorry for confusion. Is my question clear now?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I saw this in a theorem about the properties of the Stieltjes Integral where we have to prove that integration can be split up  about a point inside the interval. Here in this case the point is c.

Comment: I've modified your inequality to include the information you still didn't include except in in your reply to TheoBendit. Please look it over, and give it some consideration to see if you can see now why it is only an inequality, not an equation. (My earlier comment is not applicable - I was misinterpreting $\alpha$ and $U$ - the former is understandable, but I should have realized that my interpretation was not an upper sum.)

Comment: @deep Between your edit and Paul's editing in of your comments, this is certainly a significant improvement. There were simply too many things left unstated for me to hazard a guess as to what you're meaning. Thank you for responding. Just as a final piece of confirmation, the $U(P, f, \alpha)$ notation matches that found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Darboux_sums), correct?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you so much for improving my question.

Comment: Yes! The notation matches with Wikipedia with only difference of I have used α instead of g( used on Wikipedia page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you have it backwards:

If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are obtained by
$P_1 = \{t \in P : t \leq c\} \cup \{c\}$,
$P_2 = \{c\}\cup \{t \in P : c \leq t\}$, then $$U(P, f, α) \ge U(P_1, f, α) + U(P_2, f, α)$$
With equality holding in particular when $c\in P$.

However, $$\inf \{U(P,f,\alpha) : P\text{ partitions }[a,b]\} =\\ \inf \{U(P,f,\alpha) : P\text{ partitions }[a,c]\} + \inf \{U(P,f,\alpha) : P\text{ partitions }[c,b]\}$$

These hold because if in a partition $P$ of $[a,b], c$ falls between two adjacent partition points $p_i < c < p_{i+1}$, then the correspoding partitions  $P_1$ and $P_2$ include the intervals $[p_i,c]$ and $[c,p_{i+1}]$. All other intervals in $P_1$ and $P_2$ are also intervals in $P$, and the contributions to the upper sums from those intervals are the same. However, $U(P,f,\alpha)$ has the term $$(\max_{[p_i,p_{i+1}]} f)(\alpha(p_{i+1}) - \alpha(p_i))$$
where $U(P_1,f,\alpha) + U(P_1,f,\alpha)$ has the terms
$$(\max_{[p_i,c]} f)(\alpha(c) - \alpha(p_i)) + (\max_{[c,p_{i+1}]} f)(\alpha(p_{i+1}) - \alpha(c))$$
If the two maximums have the same value, then that will also be the maximum over all $[p_i,p_{i+1}]$, and the sum will match the term from $U(P,f,\alpha)$. But there is no reason for the two maximums to be the same. The best we can say is $$\max_{[p_i,p_{i+1}]} f = \max\{\max_{[p_i,c]} f, \max_{[c,p_{i+1}]} f\}$$
so in general we only have
$$U(P, f, α) \ge U(P_1, f, α) + U(P_2, f, α)$$

But if $c \in P$, then every interval of $P$ is in $P_1$ or $P_2$, and the sums are equal.

When we take the infimums over all partitions, we get the same inequality. But for any partition $P_1$ of $[a,c]$ and any partition $P_2$ of $[c,b]$, their union is a partition of $[a,b]$, having $c$ as one of the partition points. So $U(P_1 \cup P_2, f,\alpha) = U(P_1, f,\alpha) + U(P_2, f, \alpha)$. Thus
$\{U(P,f,\alpha) : P\text{ partitions }[a,b]\}$ includes the sum of every pair of values from $\{U(P,f,\alpha) : P\text{ partitions }[a,c]\}$ and $\{U(P,f,\alpha) : P\text{ partitions }[c,b]\}$. So its infimum cannot be any higher than the sum of the infimums of the other two sets. Which means equality holds.